# beacon distance in feet

Tags: android, beacon

How I can get the distance of a beacon in feet.can any one help me.This code gives me distance in meters

```
                        int b = Math.round(range);
                        int rssi1=rssi;
                        int txpower=-59;
                        Double distance=getDistance(rssi1,txpower);
                        int a = (int) (distance + 0.5);
```

Comment: simply convert metre to feets

Comment: will it work..?

Comment: or else are there any specific constants like TxPower for feet

Answer (score 2):

Just convert meter into feet...

1m = 3.280839895ft

```
distanceInFeet = distanceInMeter * 3.2808
```

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy this code in your java file. and can get a distance in feet as,

```
double distanceInFeet = meterToFeet(distance);


public double meterToFeet(int distanceInMeter) {
    // as 1 meter = 3.28084 feet we have.  
    return 3.28084 * distanceInMeter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// 1 metre = 3.28084 feet

```
                    int b = Math.round(range);
                    int rssi1=rssi;
                    int txpower=-59;
                    Double distance=getDistance(rssi1,txpower);
                    int a = (int) (distance + 0.5);
                    float feet = a*(3.28) ;
```